# Combine data from an array of objects based on one of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Having an array of objects like this:

```
[{"event_id":1,"person":"John"},
 {"event_id":2,"person":"John"},
 {"event_id":3,"person":"Mike"},
 {"event_id":1,"person":"Mike"},
 {"event_id":1,"person":"Anna"},
 {"event_id":3,"person":"Anna"}]
```

the wanted result should combine them based on the `event_id` and show them in a table structure like this:

```
1 John, Mike, Ana
2 John
3 Mike, Anna
```

Each row represents an event and the rows contains the people who participated in that event.
I don't know how do to this in JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [
    { event_id: 1, person: 'John' },
    { event_id: 2, person: 'John' },
    { event_id: 3, person: 'Mike' },
    { event_id: 1, person: 'Mike' },
    { event_id: 1, person: 'Anna' },
    { event_id: 3, person: 'Anna' },
];

const result = data.reduce(
    (acc, val) => ({
        ...acc,
        [val.event_id]: acc[val.event_id] ? [...acc[val.event_id], val.person] : [val.person],
    }),
    {},
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to first group your objects, where the `event_id` is the key in the map, and the value is an array of accumulated `person` values for the same `event_id` values. You can then use `Array.from()` to map each `[key, value]` entry to a string of HTML for the table rows and data. You can then add this string to your HTML like so:

```js
const arr = [{"event_id":1,"person":"John"},
 {"event_id":2,"person":"John"},
 {"event_id":3,"person":"Mike"},
 {"event_id":1,"person":"Mike"},
 {"event_id":1,"person":"Anna"},
 {"event_id":3,"person":"Anna"}];
 
const table = `
  <table>
    ${Array.from(
      arr.reduce((m, {event_id:id, person}) => m.set(id, [...(m.get(id) || []), person]), new Map), 
      ([key, arr]) => `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${arr.join(', ')}</td></tr>`
    ).join('')}
  </table>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data type.

Map is a collection of keyed data items, just like an Object. But the
main difference is that Map allows keys of any type.
First of all we iterate on Array of Objects, then we check if there is any event_id in Map  we push Object.person to the value of event_id entry :

```
const listOfObjects = [
    { "event_id": 1, "person": "John" },
    { "event_id": 2, "person": "John" },
    { "event_id": 3, "person": "Mike" },
    { "event_id": 1, "person": "Mike" },
    { "event_id": 1, "person": "Anna" },
    { "event_id": 3, "person": "Anna" }];
let eventIdCollection = new Map();
listOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
    if (eventIdCollection.has(obj.event_id)) {
        let persons = eventIdCollection.get(obj.event_id);
        persons.push(obj.person);
        eventIdCollection.set(obj.event_id, persons);
    }
    else {
        eventIdCollection.set(obj.event_id, [obj.person]);
    }
});
```

the result is Map of event_id to Array of persons.